Importing data from Google Business Review to Python `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`
I am trying to import data from Google Business Reviews into Python but keep running into this error `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch` even though I followed the documentation Google post where I was told to follow the steps:

Enable the Google Reviews API.
Create a project in the Google Developers Console.
Enable the Google Reviews API in your project.
Create a service account.
Download the JSON key file for your service account.
Install the Google API client library for your programming language.
Create a new client object.
Call the accounts.locations.reviews.list() method to get a list of reviews for your business.
To get just the reviews, you can call the accounts.locations.reviews.list() method with the following parameters:


account_id: The ID of your Google My Business account.
location_id: The ID of your Google My Business location.
filter: A filter that can be used to narrow down the results. For example, you can use the rating filter to only get reviews with a certain rating.

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=http://localhost:52271/ flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

The number 52271 seems to keep changing even though I tried to keep it fixed in my code as 8080:

import requests
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from loguru import logger as log

# Your Google My Business account ID and location ID
my_business_account_id = "..." # Replace with actual
location_id = "..." # Replace with actual

# OAuth 2.0 access token obtained
access_token = "..."  # Replace with your actual access token

# Path to your OAuth 2.0 Client Secret JSON file
GCP_CREDENTIALS_PATH = "google_review_client.json" # Replace with actual


# Ensure the redirect URI matches the one in Google Cloud Console
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/"


# Setup the OAuth 2.0 flow with required scopes
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    GCP_CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage"],
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
)

# Run the OAuth flow to obtain credentials
credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

# Log the credentials to confirm successful OAuth
log.debug(f"Credentials: {credentials}")

# Setup session to use the credentials for accessing Google My Business API
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(
    {"Authorization": f"Bearer {credentials.token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
)

# Construct the API endpoint URL
url = f"https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{my_business_account_id}/locations/{location_id}/reviews"

# Perform the API request and handle potential errors
try:
    log.info(f"Making API request to URL: {url}")
    response = session.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()  # This will raise an error for bad HTTP status codes
    reviews = response.json()
    log.success("Reviews fetched successfully.")
    print(reviews)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_err:
    log.error(
        f"HTTP error occurred: {http_err}"
    )  # Specific details about the HTTP error
except Exception as err:
    log.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {err}")  # Other errors

I am expecting a table with the Google reviews for the business but when I run this I am getting the error Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch.

You may consider using the Google Cloud SDK's [gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login https://github.com/dresenhista/google_my_business) command to authenticate your application. This method automatically handles authorization and simplifies the process.
The reason why the number 52271 keeps changing even though you've tried to fix it as 8080 is likely due to port conflicts. This usually happens when:

Another application or process on your system is already using port 8080, your app will be assigned a different port number to avoid conflicts. This is why you see the number changing.

Your development environments or frameworks might dynamically assign port numbers to applications, especially when running multiple instances simultaneously. This can also cause the port number to change.


With this, you may consider the following workarounds which might help:

Check for conflicting processes: Use the netstat command in your terminal to see which processes are listening on port 8080. If another process is using it, you'll need to stop it or change its port.

Specify a different port in your code: Instead of hardcoding port 8080, you can specify a different port that is less likely to be in use. For example, try using port 8081 or 8082.

Configure your development environment: If you're using a development environment like Node.js or Django, check its documentation for instructions on how to specify a fixed port for your application.

Use a port-forwarding tool: If you're running your app on a local machine and need to access it from a remote device, you can use a port-forwarding tool like ngrok to expose a public URL for your application.


If none of the information above help you to fix the issue you may also look to this repository of dresenhista about Pulling Review from Google My Business with Python wherein she created her own code to pull all the reviews from Google My Business and then analyze which subjects people talk more about her business.

Oh this is nice! I was hoping to do it programatically though so I can pull it in on a set cadence
